# Metropolis Hastings Algorithm and Breaking Reversibility in MCMC

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

If the goal is to sample from a distribution $\pi$ it is common to build a Markov Chain with stationary distribution $\pi$. Solving this problem using Markov Chain Monte Carlo is essentially simulating the Markov chain, and taking the values it achieves as (an approximation of) samples from $\pi$.

Consider the overdamped Langevin equation, for which it is well-known that $\pi$ is stationary (infact reversible).
$$
dX_t=\nabla \log \pi(X_t) dt+\sqrt{2}dW_t, 
$$

A common choice of Markov chain is a discretisation of $X_t$. Recently there has been huge amount of literature (e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-016-1565-1) showing that it is favourable to use non-reversible dynamics like the perturbed underdamped Langevin equation

$$
dX_t=\nabla \log \pi(X_t) dt+b(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dW_t,~~~\text{with}~~~\text{div}(\pi(x) b(x))=0.
$$
For which $\pi$ is stationary (not reversible). However a discretisation of $X$ will not have $\pi$ as its stationary distribution. To fix this people use Metropolis Hastings algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm. But the Metropolis Hastings algorithm constructs a reversible process (by definition), so my $\textbf{question :}$ are the benefits gained from using non-reversible dynamics completely lost when we use the Metropolis Hasting algorithm?

Comment: There exist versions of the Langevin algorithm without the Metropolis Hastings step: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-25/issue-4A/High-dimensional-Bayesian-inference-via-the-unadjusted-Langevin-algorithm/10.3150/18-BEJ1073.full

Comment: @Xi'an so the ULA converge to $\pi$ even though it is a discretisation of the continuous time dynamics?

Comment: yes, but you need to check the paper, as they (and others) use a diminishing time step. See also https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~teh/research/compstats/WelTeh2011a.pdf